# How to make a COUNT with better performace?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

Im using this query, which takes 3 secounds to run. The table announces has 255k rows and the table address has 30k rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ad.id) as total_address
FROM (
  SELECT
    ad.id, an.id as announce_id,
    an.buy_price as buy_price,
    an.rental_price as rental_price,
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_address 
      WHERE address_id = ad.id) as totalOwnersAd,
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_announce 
      WHERE announce_id = an.id) as totalOwnersAn
  FROM addresses ad
  RIGHT JOIN announces an ON ad.id = an.address_id
  WHERE an.name = 'tralala' and ad.name = 'tralala'
) ad
```

And the subquery:

```
SELECT
  ad.id, an.id as announce_id,
  an.buy_price as buy_price,
  an.rental_price as rental_price,
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_address 
    WHERE address_id = ad.id) as totalOwnersAd,
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_announce 
    WHERE announce_id = an.id) as totalOwnersAn
FROM addresses ad
RIGHT JOIN announces an ON ad.id = an.address_id
WHERE an.name = 'tralala' and ad.name = 'tralala'
```

takes 17ms to run.

Why my `COUNT`is taking so long?

Im using MySql.

I need to join `announces` and `addresses` tables because of my dynamic filter. For example, when I need to count address that has an announce column X equals to Y.

EDIT:

I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ad.address_id) as total_address
        FROM announces an JOIN ( 
           SELECT adds.id as address_id
                FROM (
                      SELECT id,
                      (SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_address WHERE address_id = ad.id) as totalOwnersAd
                      from addresses ad


             )  as adds
        ) as ad ON ad.address_id = an.address_id
        WHERE 
         ( an.bedroom = 2 )
```

Its 10% faster, but it still takes to long. When I have address filter It goes faster.

Is there anyway to index the sub query table?

Comment: Probably because you are counting 17 milliseconds to when the *first* row is returned rather than when the *last* row is returned.  Your first subquery needs to process all the data.

Comment: Why do you have that outer query? You could just remove all the columns and expressions after `SELECT` in the inner query and instead add the `count()` there. The optimizer probably does that anyway, so it might not impact performance but readability a lot.

Comment: @stickybit I edit my question to explain it better.

Comment: If I create an temporary table and index id, would it be a solution?

Comment: Do you have your tables indexed?  How?

Comment: I have announce id indexed and address id indexed. I think that If I could index my sub query table I would solve the problem, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason to say `RIGHT`?  If not, please remove it.  Does the `COUNT(ad.id)` need `DISTINCT`?  Can it be computed without doing the `JOIN`; if so, this is a big optimization.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to know what indexes you have, plus other things.

Comment: Please do not reuse alias names (`ad`).  It makes it hard to parse and hard to know if MySQL will parse it the same way.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each select you show.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just curious why you don't use:

```
select count(distinct an.address_id)
from announces;
```

It seems like a simpler method to arrive at the same value.

EDIT:

For your revised query, this is simpler:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT an.address_id)
FROM addresses ad JOIN
     announces an
     ON ad.id = an.address_id
WHERE an.name = 'tralala' and ad.name = 'tralala';
```

The `right join` is unnecessary, because the `WHERE` conditions turn it into an `inner join`.  The subqueries and additional columns are not necessary.

Comment: I cant use because my query takes dynamic where and Its needs

Comment: @TiagoCastro - As I see - This query will return exactly the same result as your first query.

Comment: I cant to do it, because of my dyamic where filter that needs to right join announces. For example, when I need to count address that has my announce_name equals to 'the'.

Comment: @TiagoCastro You can append your WHERE condition to this query as well.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the problem is that my WHERE condition needs both tables ( announces and address) at the same time. For example: WHERE address.name = 'lala' AND announces.name = 'lalala'

Comment: And remove those inner select count(*) because they only consume time **(SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_address 
    WHERE address_id = ad.id) as totalOwnersAd,
  (SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_announce 
    WHERE announce_id = an.id) as totalOwnersAn**

Comment: The problem is that something my users filter has `totalOwnersAd > 0`, If I do that I wont be able to do this with `HAVING`

Answer (score -1):

Ok, After to much thinking I reduce in 15x times, its not perfect but its ok now.

My query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ad.address_id) as total_address
        FROM (
           SELECT ann.id as announce_id, ann.buy_price as buy_price, ann.address_id as address_id,
            ann.rental_price as rental_price

            FROM (
                SELECT id, buy_price, rental_price, address_id,
                  (SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_announce 
  WHERE announce_id = an.id) as totalOwnersAn
              FROM announces an
              WHERE 
               ( an.parking_slots = 2 ) AND ( an.bedroom = 2 ) 
    ) as ann
) as anner
 JOIN ( 
           SELECT adds.id as address_id
                FROM (
                      SELECT id,
                      (SELECT Count(*) FROM owner_address WHERE address_id = ad.id) as totalOwnersAd
                      from addresses ad
                      WHERE 
                      city LIKE '%Campinas%'
             )  as adds
        ) as ad ON ad.address_id = anner.address_id
```